# python how to convert python long string with dynamic values to more structural pattern

Tags: python-3.x, string, dynamic

i have this legacy code which contains long string with dynamic values :
For example : in reality, the string is much longer and there is a need to add more values over time

```
my_vars = "key1=value1 " \
                         "key2=%s key3='%s' key4=%s key5=%s key6=%s " \
                         "key7=\"%s\" key8='%s'"  % (
                value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8)
```

this is cumbersome what can i do to build some other struct that will convert to string but will be more structural pattern

Comment: How about `dict`? You could also write your own `DynStrings` class, and store the strings by your requirements.

Comment: what is DynStrings class?

Comment: Just a class name I made up. If you could provide more information on how your struct should function, I can post (an answer) how I would store dynamic strings in `python`. A simple class can handle efficiently your data storing, and the conversion to `str`.

Comment: currently, this is what i have simple as that , i want to convert it to more robust 
and easy to add key+values

Comment: Can two different strings have the same key?

Comment: no should be unique

Comment: Alright, try my answer. If strrings are unique you need to add `if` statements and check it. Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your values in a `list` and use a more modern string formatting pattern:

```
values = [value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8]

my_vars = " ".join("key{i}={v}".format(i=i, v=v) for i, v in enumerate(values))
# or in Python >= 3.8
# my_vars = " ".join(f"key{i}={v}" for i, v in enumerate(values))
```

Comment: no i like it to be structural, it will be still amess for setting more keys

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *structural*?

Comment: i mean if i like to add more key + value i will just do add(key,value) 
and in the end it will convert to string

Comment: Why not just use a `dict`? Set key as you always would `dct[key] = value` and have a function to serialize it?

Comment: I'm afraid it will be a performance problem to convert large dict to string in each request

Answer (score 0):

You could use a written `DynStrings` class that handles this type of data for you:

```
class DynStrings:
    def __init__(self, st=""):
        self.data = []
        if st:
            self.data = [[x.split('=')[0], x.split('=')[1]] for x in st.split(' ')]

    def load(self, st):
        self.__init__(st)

    def add(self, key, val):
        self.data.append([key, val])

    def add_str(self, st):
        tmp = self.data.copy()
        self.load(st)
        self.data = tmp + self.data

    def change(self, old_key, val):
        for i in self.data:
            if i[0] == old_key:
                i[1] = val

    def remove_key(self, key):
        for i in self.data:
            if i[0] == key:
                self.data.remove(i)

    def remove_val(self, val):
        for i in self.data:
            if i[1] == val:
                self.data.remove(i)

    def tostr(self):
        return ' '.join([f"{x[0]}={x[1]}" for x in self.data])
```

You can now use it to store dynamic data. It allows to load data from a `string` or the values themselves. The function `tostr()` converts your struct back to string by the mentioned format.

```
data = DynStrings()
data.load("key1=value1 key2=value2")
data.add("key3", "value3")
data.add_str("key4=value4 key5=value5")
data.change("key4", "new_value")
print(data.tostr())
```